# Receive from socket until specific line in C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I created this little client socket in C#:

```
TcpClient socket = new TcpClient(this.ip, this.port);
NetworkStream stream = socket.GetStream();
StreamReader input = new StreamReader(stream);
StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(stream);

output.WriteLine(request);
output.Flush();

String result = "";
String line = "";
while (line != "GO")
{
    line = input.ReadLine().Trim();
    result += line + "\n";
}

socket.Close();
return result;
```

It connects just fine, but it stays stuck in the while loop, it will only receive the first line the server socket sends, so the "GO" is never received. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you give more details about the server-side code? Also, as an aside, `input.ReadLine().Trim()` is dangerous here because `ReadLine()` returns `null` if the stream is exhausted. If the server closes the connection without sending the `GO` line, your client application will die.

Comment: Are you sure that "GO" isn't being received?  If you send "GO" with other data without a newline character before it, then you'll read off more than just "GO" during that ReadLine() call and 'line' will not equal "GO" which would explain why you aren't exiting the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because it is waiting for data, which will hang your application.

You might need to use a `TcpListener` instead and call `AcceptTcpClient()` when receiving data.

Further, I always call this in a thread or BackgroundWorker so that the interface does not hang.

If you need the TcpListerner to stop listening for a TCP connection, then you would call the `Stop()` method of the instance.